# Change MAC address Cocoa - Objective-C

Tags: objective-c, macos, cocoa, bash, mac-address

How can I change the MAC address via Objective-C? Looking for a simple solution. I already have a shell script (Bash) that can do it if that helps. How would I open that from my Cocoa application? Thanks.

Comment: What's this?! A Cocoa question that uses "MAC" correctly! Is the world coming to an end? :-)

Answer (score 2):

You can run external commands using [NSTask](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSTask_Class/Reference/Reference.html).

However, it's likely that changing the MAC address requires superuser privileges so you will have to look into [authorization](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#samplecode/BetterAuthorizationSample/Introduction/Intro.html) as well.