# Obtaining and changing MAC address using objective-C in OS X

Tags: objective-c, macos, osx-yosemite, mac-address

How can I obtain and then change MAC address using objective-C? The solution was suggested only for iOS: [How can I programmatically get the MAC address of an iphone](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/677530/how-can-i-programmatically-get-the-mac-address-of-an-iphone)

Comment: See [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10593736/mac-address-from-interface-on-os-x-c) for reading the MAC address. See also [Change MAC address Cocoa - Objective-C](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4825332/change-mac-address-cocoa-objective-c) of which your question is probably a duplicate.

Comment: thanx, but it would be interesting how to achieve the goal without a shell script, just purely objective-C.

Answer (score 1):

This is setup a startup script to modify the MAC address each time you restart the computer.

```
#!/bin/sh
. /etc/rc.common

StartService () {
    networksetup -setairportpower en0 on
    networksetup -setairportpower en1 on
    /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/Apple80211.framework/Resources/airport -z
    /sbin/ifconfig en0 ether 00:`openssl rand -hex 5 | sed 's/\(..\)/\1:/g; s/.$//'`
    /sbin/ifconfig en1 ether 00:`openssl rand -hex 5 | sed 's/\(..\)/\1:/g; s/.$//'`
    networksetup -detectnewhardware
}

StopService () { return 0 }

RestartService () { return 0 }

RunService "$1"
```

Not directly using Objective-C but you can run a shell script from Obj-C using NSTask.  [More on that here.](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17977235/1922144)

I compiled this into a little installer a while back for a buddy.  If you want the package, [it's available here](https://github.com/dcondrey/Spiffy).

Comment: How does this answer the question?